# How discretely defined visibility of my assemblies types?

Tags: c#, .net, types, visibility, .net-assembly

I'm using the *.NET 4.5.2* and need access from assembly B a *ClassA* defined in assembly A, but want declare *ClassA* as internal to avoid access from other assemblies to it.

I don't want use *InternalsVisibleTo* because I don't want all the assembly A types internal end exposed to the assembly B.

Summarizing: I need discretely defined visibility of my assemblies types. Is that possible?

EDIT: [StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission.aspx) is very similar to what I need, but I just don't want the types be public, because I want them hided at the compiling time too.

Comment: The fact that you are trying to do this indicates an architectural flaw in your design. Why are there even two assemblies in the first place?

Comment: @EricLippert completely disagree with you. Is not trivial explain why I need to give access to another assemblies to the classes of one assembly discretely, but basically is related with DDD layered architecture and the fact that some Domain *Reconstruction Factories* need to be accessed from the Infrastructure Layer and not from the Application Layer, and some *Creation Factories* have just to be access from the Application Layer and not from the infrastructure layer. This is just one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to move class A out to new project by itself?  Then you can just reference project A from project B and no other projects / assemblies will see it.

If that's not possible then I agree with Eric that the design seems incorrect.  It would be like having this standard project structure:

```
project Entity
project Database
project Server
project UserInterface
```

but in your case you are lumping say Entity and Database together.  And so when UserInterface needs to use Entities, it also has to include useless database code.

Comment: To you have a correct opinion about my design I have explain you more about it, and that is kind of off-topic in this context. I just wanted be sure that not exist a solution to that technical problem I have because my design. If you know about DDD may be you can understand something about my design: Domain define Constructor and Creation Factories both consumed in different layers (Infrastructure and Application), so the Domain Layer need expose both kind of classes to different kind of layers. I don't want initiate a discussion about my design, that would be an off-topic.

Comment: Sure but is it not possible to just split the physical domain project into Domain.Infrastructure and Domain.Application projects?  They would still form a single domain layer but you would be able to control the visibility that way.

Comment: Of course, but then I would be splitting my Domain layer in different assemblies (with all the cost in maintenance that have) just to solve the technical problem of "not having the possibility to discretely expose to certain assemblies my types". We already model the thing in that way and we end with a lot of extra assemblies, that is why I ask this question, I'm not looking for advice to redefine my architecture or how implement it using trivial .NET concepts, but to solve that specific technical problem, still, I really appreciate your effort for help me. Thanks you.

Comment: I totally understand, it actually annoys me when people try to solve the problem by telling to you redesign.  But in this case in particular i get the feeling there is no technical solution so my comments are really in the case that a solution can't be found.  You've probably already checked out the special attributes used for testing which can sometimes be used to dive into hidden parts of assemblies.  I would suggest if the issue is important that you try posting a simplified project structure with some small factory methods using DDD to show the problem in a concrete way.

Comment: Thanks you one more time, I really appreciate your help. I will check the special attributes used for testing, I don't think about ;) Thanks you again!